# Creating an .htaccess file?

Tags: .htaccess

How to create an .htaccess file? Is it required to restart the server after creating an .htaccess file?

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCompatibility2 On
RepeatLimit 200
RewriteBase 
# unsupported directive: [ISAPI_Rewrite]

RewriteCond %{HTTP:Host} ^xxx\.com$
RewriteRule (.*) http\://www.xxxx.com$1 [NC,R=301,U]
RewriteRule ^/main.html$ http\://www.xxx.com/index.cfm [NC,R=301,U]

ErrorDocument 404 /Errors.htm
```

Thanks in advance.

Comment: How in the name of rabid kittens did this get migrated to Server Fault? I see a nonsensical question ("How to create an .htaccess file?" - With a text editor, and the syntax in the Apache manual), a question that can be answered in 30 seconds by reading the Apache manual ("is it required to restart the server after creating an .htaccess file?" - No.), and what appears to be someone's `.htaccess` file.

Answer (score 3):

> how to create .htaccess file?

Open text editor. Start typing.

You might have to fight your editor to allow you to save a file that "only has an extension". You might have to fight your uploader software (if you are creating the file on a different system to the server) to get it to see the file.

> is it required to restart the server after creating .htaccess file

No. Most of the point of .htaccess is that it is handled on-the-fly.

Answer (score 1):

No, restarting is only required when changing httpd.conf files or vhosts files. `.htaccess` files don't require a restart.

Answer (score 1):

`.htaccess` is regular text file. And you do not need to restart the server. It will be processed on next request

Answer (score 0):

You don't need to restart the server after creating or changing the .htaccess file. Place the .htaccess file in the folder where the rules need to apply to. You can have different .htaccess files for different folders on your server.